# Change helper ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, helper

I made a draggable, sortable div and what I want is to change the clone ID after dragging it, but my script changes the IDs of both the original and the clone.  My code is as follows:

```
var i = 0;
     $('#colum').draggable({

                            helper:'clone',
                            connectToSortable:'#sort',
                            start: function(event,ui) {
                            i++;
                            $(this).attr("id","colum"+i);
                           }
                          });   
          $('#sort').sortable({ 
                    connectWith: "#sort",
                    containment: "#sort" 
          )};
```

Comment: i tryed ui.helper in the place of 'this' but i got same result

Comment: any idea? with ui.draggable too both original id and clone id change

Comment: I'm not familiar of that part of UI but I suggest that you use console.log(this); to see what it contains. If there is just the #column then maybe you clone it afterwards the ID is changed?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to change the ID of the clone?

Answer (score 0):

You can get at the sortable helper by accessing the `ui` variable passed into the `start` event - `ui.helper`.

```
$('#sort').sortable({ 
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.attr('id', 'mycustomid'); //ui.helper is a jquery object pointing to the helper
    },
    connectWith: "#sort",
    containment: "#sort"
)};
```

Comment: yes actually it change it but only while its dragged when i drop it return to same id

Comment: @user653826 that's because the clone is destroyed when the drag operation completes and the original takes it's place. If you could tell me why you want to change the clone ID I could give you a better answer.

Comment: simply cause in my application every bloc must gave his own id so i can modify it later

Comment: @user653826 but the helper/clone is created only when dragging. It doesn't exist after the dragging is completed. You won't need to modify it later. If you want to give an ID to your element, simply use html